# Can't catch a FileNotFoundException when using DOMConfigurator

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code:

```
try {  
    DOMConfigurator.configure(url+log4j.xml);
} catch(Exception e) {   
    e.printStackTrace();   
}
```

And I would expect a `FileNotFoundException` if the log4j.xml doesn't exist, and then the catch-block would be executed.

But I don't see an exception when the file doesn't exist, why is that?

Comment: you mean FileNotFoundException s thrown instead being caught in catch block ?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [the source of DOMConfigurator.doConfigure](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.java?view=markup) it looks like it catches `Exception` and then just logs the error rather than rethrowing it. Therefore the `FileNotFoundException` will not make it back to your calling code.

```
try {
...
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof InterruptedException || e instanceof InterruptedIOException) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    // I know this is miserable...
    LogLog.error("Could not parse "+ action.toString() + ".", e);
}
```

To work around this you could preemptively check if the file exists yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try catching a Throwable instead of an Exception and do a print stack trace. That way you can catch any errors or exceptions and change your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to disable those messages from log4j, you can set log4j in quiet mode:

```
LogLog.setQuietMode(true);
```